# Adjust grid in R plot

Tags: r

I'm ploting a vector of 29 values in a plot using:

```
plot(0:29, v, type="o", main="Title of the plot")
```

I try to adjust the grid to be unit by unit using:

```
grid(31, lw=2)
```

The problem is that x axis first value (0 position) doesn't start at the begining of the graph and grid starts at the begining, so both elements aren't aligned.

How can solve this issue?

Comment: What's `v`? .... And that's 30 values, not 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `abline` instead.

```
plot(0:10)
abline(h = 0:10)
abline(v = 0:10)
```

You can also force the exact x and y limits:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10, xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0, 10), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
grid(10)
```

In general, using `abline` is easier and more robust. I also often plot with `type = "n"`, add lines/whatever in the background, then add the points.

Comment: Vertical abline works fine, but `abline(h=0:4, lty=2, col="lightgrey")`
 doesn't work.

Comment: Horitzontal lines aren't printed in the plot, but vertical lines are printed well.

Comment: I think you must have a mistake on your end. If you copy and paste the code I have provided you should be able to see that it works.

Comment: The problem is that the limits of my yaxis goes from 0.4 to 0.75, so abline in horitzontal position cannot be printed.
The solution that I found is to print the grid using `grid()` and overplot abline(v...).

Comment: @P.Rodoreda Please read the man pages for `abline`. It simply draws lines at the x or y values you specify. You can give the function any sequence of values.